# Adding a ASP:Button with event in table from serverside

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to implement a delete function(button) to an existing table. I cant change the way its done, so i needs to done as a stringbuilder. is there anyway that you can make a asp:button or just a button that will fire and event onclick in a stringbuilder? just adding it to the stringbuilder renders it as plain html and not as a control.

What ive tried:

```
  foreach (SortableNode n in nodes)
  {
    html.AppendLine(
      "<tr id='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' " + (n.sortOder == 0 ? " class='sortsep'" : "") + ">" +
        "<td>" + n.Name + "<input type='hidden' name='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' id='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' value='" + n.id.ToString() + "' /></td>" +
        "<td class='nowrap'>" + n.createDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "</td>" + 
        "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + n.sortOder + "</td>" + 
        "<td><asp:Button id=\"BuTOTNON" + counter +"\" cssClass=\"btnDelLink\" runat=\"server\" CommandArgument=\"" + n.id + "\" OnClick=\"bDelete_Click\" Text='X'/>" + "</td>" + 
      "</tr>");
  }
      lt_nodes.Text = html.ToString();
```

Or an easy way of doing this client side with JS?

Comment: You will have to use dynamically created controls and add them to the page from code behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone finding this, ive made it work, but replacing the "litteral placeholder" with an actual placer holder and did it as such:

```
  foreach (SortableNode n in nodes)
  {

    Button deleteBtn = new Button();
    deleteBtn.Text = "X";
    deleteBtn.Click += new EventHandler(bDelete_Click);
    deleteBtn.ID = n.id.ToString();

    html.AppendLine(
    "<tr id='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' " + (n.sortOder == 0 ? " class='sortsep'" : "") + ">" +
      "<td>" + n.Name + "<input type='hidden' name='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' id='" + NodeIdName() + n.id.ToString() + "' value='" + n.id.ToString() + "' /></td>" +
      "<td class='nowrap'>" + n.createDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "</td>" +
      "<td style='text-align: center;'>" + n.sortOder + "</td><td>"
    );

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(html.ToString()));
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(deleteBtn);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</td></tr>"));
  }
```